# Issue in adding and subtracting old value

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, addition

Here I am having very short problem regarding my garage application...let us take one small schenario to understand my app.When some car came to wash I am taking 300 rs and the owner of car is giving 500 rs and so I have to give 200 rs so now total income is 300 rs...and when I am buying some accessories from same amt lets say 50rs..now My total will remain 250 rs and when I am submitting it is stored in database now I want same total amount again 250 rs and need addition and subtraction from same 250.so here I am facing problem in addition and subtraction from last amount..I had used shared preference for that but condition is wrong...
here is my code:

```
    acceptmoney_edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.acceptmoney_edt);
    givenmoney_edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.givenmoney_edt);
    totalincome_edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.totalincome_edt);
    note_edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note_edt);
    date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
    totalincome_edt.setEnabled(false);

    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
    alldata = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alldata);
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreference= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String valuee=(mSharedPreference.getString("Neel", ""));
    value=Double.parseDouble(valuee);

    totalincome_edt.setText(valuee);

    alldata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Recyclerview_neel.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            acceptmoney_edt.setText("");
            givenmoney_edt.setText("");
            note_edt.setText("");

        }
    });

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Recyclerview_neel.class);
            startActivity(i);

            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("Neel", totalincome_edt.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();

            long l = 0;
            DAL dal = new DAL(getApplicationContext());
            dal.OpenDB();
            l = dal.InsertQryForTabEmpData(
                    totalincome_edt.getText().toString()
                    , acceptmoney_edt.getText().toString()
                    , givenmoney_edt.getText().toString()
                    , note_edt.getText().toString()
                    , date.getText().toString()


            );
            dal.CloseDB();


        }
    });


    acceptmoney_edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {



            Double v1 = Double.parseDouble(!acceptmoney_edt.getText().toString().isEmpty() ?
                    acceptmoney_edt.getText().toString() : "0");
            Double v2 = Double.parseDouble(!givenmoney_edt.getText().toString().isEmpty() ?
                    givenmoney_edt.getText().toString() : "0");
            value = (v1 - v2);
            totalincome_edt.setText(value.toString());
        }
    });

    givenmoney_edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            Double v1 = Double.parseDouble(!acceptmoney_edt.getText().toString().isEmpty() ?
                    acceptmoney_edt.getText().toString() : "0");
            Double v2 = Double.parseDouble(!givenmoney_edt.getText().toString().isEmpty() ?
                    givenmoney_edt.getText().toString() : "0");
            value = (v1 - v2);
            totalincome_edt.setText(value.toString());
        }
    });


    //time
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int mSeconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    //date
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    date.setText(mHour + ":" + mMinute + ":" + mSeconds + "  " + sdf.format(new Date()));
    date.setEnabled(false);


}
```

Thank you In advance

Comment: check how much times afterTextChanged is getting called. In my case its getting call 3 times when I do single time keyboard press

Comment: No problem in this bro...but problem is in value=value+(v1-v2)